# Issue: Node Express can't get session value with post request

Tags: node.js, express, session, shopify

I am developing a Shopify App in node.js. I am using different Shopify webhooks for different actions. similarly for a specific scenario I need to use session value while I am getting response from Shopify API. So in this scenario the session is not working for me. Please have a look on below code.

My code in index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var session = require('express-session');
app.set('trust proxy', 1); // trust first proxy  
app.use(session({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        httpOnly: false,
        secure: true,
        maxAge: 60000
    }
}));

//Set the session  
app.get('/check_timewindow_orders', function (req, res, next) {
    req.session.delvy_date = query.date_select;
});

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.locals.delvy_date = req.session.delvy_date;
    next();
});
```

I get the session value in app.get and app.post.

```
app.get('/order_created_get', function (req, res) {  
console.log(req.cookies.delDate);   
    // It display the value store in session.  
});
```

But I cannot get the session value when I get the post from shopify Order Create Webhook API.

```
app.post('/order_created', function (req, res) {  
    console.log(req.cookies.delDate); // It display Null.  
});
```

Comment: It's easier for others to find what issue is if you could format your code nicer with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually using the session.
You need to add it as middleware:

```
app.get('/check_timewindow_orders', session, function(req, res, next){  
    req.session.delvy_date = req.query.date_select;  
}); 

app.use(session, function(req, res, next) {  
    res.locals.delvy_date = req.session.delvy_date;   
    next();  
});
```

Comment: Hi There,
Many thanks for your reply, Yes i have also tried your method but still  not get the session value when i am getting Response from Shopify API.

Comment: You were also not using `req.query.date_select`. That should have thrown an error though

Comment: Further i also used req.query.date_select but did not get the session value :(

Comment: I am getting issue for session value for below response 
    app.post('/order_created', function (req, res) {  
    req.session.delvy_date // It display Null.  
    });

Comment: You should probably update your question to show your current code.